# How to print and output from command prompt?

Tags: python, printing, command

I am new here, I'm trying to run a code that open a command prompt in python with

```py
os.system('cmd/k"command"')
```

It is working well, and I can see my code is running, but I cannot print the result in python, does someone know how to do it?

A solution to print the value in python

Comment: Your quotes are not balanced. Please post your actual code.

Comment: Use `subprocess.Popen()` or `subprocess.run()` rather than `os.system()`. You can read the output of that.

Answer (score 0):

The outcome of the command is this line of code itself.
You can do:

```py
cmd_outcome = os.system('cmd/k"command"')
print(cmd_outcome)
```